# $p$-adic Fourier transforms and orthogonality relations

Tags: fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, fourier-transform

1. In $\mathbb{C}$, we have the following orthogonality relation
   $$
   \int_{0}^{1} e^{2\pi i (m-n)x} dx = \begin{cases}
   1 & \mbox{ if } m = n;\\
   0 & \mbox{ otherwise.}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   Do we have something similar for $\mathbb{C}_p$ with $e^{2\pi i (m-n)x}$ replaced with a similar $p$-adic valued function?
2. Is there an analogue of the Fourier transform (continuous or discrete cyclic or linear) for $\mathbb{C}_p$? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{p}$? Or $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$? $C_{p}$ usually denotes the multiplicative group of order $p-1$.

Comment: @Bombyx I thought $\mathbb C_p$ usually denotes the metric completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: @ErickWong: You are right - I found the wikipedia article. Shall upvote the question as I knew nothing about it.

Comment: Watch out: $\mathbf C$ is locally compact, while $\mathbf C_p$ is not!  So traditional harmonic analysis on locally compact (abelian) groups, which is where the Fourier transform lives, is not really something that can be directly transferred from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf C_p$.

Comment: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mpopa/571/chapter3.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjYzP2cj4zNAhUCtBQKHWWlDqQQFggeMAE&usg=AFQjCNEHaCAIgcPqQKPU93kRzvlmsG3sWg

Comment: In exercise 1.4 it says that Qp is locally compact. So how about over Qp?